# SQL Server ISNULL not working in multi table selection

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL server and I'm trying to get the maximum price of an item based on the update of table and if is null to replace the null able value with zero.

Here is what I did:

```
DECLARE @itemid BIGINT

SELECT
    (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE.Price), 0.00)
     FROM ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE 
     WHERE (ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE.item_id = 7)) AS price,  
    itemunits.unit_id,
    itemunits.unit_name 
FROM 
    ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE 
INNER JOIN 
    Items ON ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE.item_id = Items.Item_id 
INNER JOIN 
    itemunits ON Items.Item_unit_id = itemunits.unit_id 
WHERE 
    (Items.Item_id = 7) 
GROUP BY
    itemunits.unit_id, itemunits.unit_name,
    ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE.update_date 
ORDER BY 
    ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE.update_date DESC;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You seem to have posted a question, however, you forgot to post a question! Whoops! You also seem to forget we can't run your query, we don't have access to your server. You'll need to also supply some sample data and expected results along with your question when you edit what you've already posted. I also suggest fostering your code as code, not in a quote, which will mean others can read what you've posted.

Comment: I think you just want `coalesce(max(item_supplier_price.price), 0.00)` without the subquery.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: thanks  shawnt00 for your reply but it still gives me nothing when the item has no record in the item_supplier_price table

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on how to improve your question.

Comment: How many rows have item_id 7 in all of those tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for the max price in the group. Since prices probably can't be negative, the second option below should be equivalent but I throw it in just in case the problem is there.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(MAX(isp.Price), 0.00) AS price1,
    MAX(COALESCE(isp.Price, 0.00)) AS price2,
    iu.unit_id,
    iu.unit_name 
FROM ITEM_SUPPLIER_PRICE isp
    INNER JOIN Items i ON i.item_id = isp.Item_id 
    INNER JOIN itemunits iu ON iu.unit_id = i.Item_unit_id
WHERE i.Item_id = 7
GROUP BY
    iu.unit_id, 
    iu.unit_name,
    isp.update_date 
ORDER BY isp.update_date desc;
```

Comment: i may couldn't completely make my question clear i'm working on procurement web app and i want to get some details related to the item selected when creating a purchasing requisition like the item highest updated price if exists and if not i will replace with zero and the item unit name and unit id  the item price is related to the vendors and can be vary from vendor to other and also the vendor may change the item price due to market change and item price record can be added only through purchase order form not requisition